# Vault Pods looping through seal/unsealed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I'm deploying Hashicorp Vault via Helm using a custom values.yaml files here:

```
server:
  enabled: true
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_ADDR: "https://hostname"
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-server-tls
  service:
    enabled: true
    port: 8200
    targetPort: 443
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      config: |
        ui = true
        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = false
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
          tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.crt"
          tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.key"
        }
        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
        }
    config: |
      ui = true
      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = false
        address = "${VAULT_ADDR}:443"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.crt"
        tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-server-tls/tls.key"
        tls_skip_verify = true
      }
      storage "consul" {
        path = "vault"
        address = "HOST_IP:8500"
      }
      disable_mlock = true

ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
  externalPort: 443
  targetPort: 8200
```

I've gotten Vault to deploy successfully. I was able to unseal it as well via the UI.
As I'm looking at the Vault pods via Lens IDE I see the 3 replicas just looping with the Warning message:

`- Readiness probe failed. Key value --- ----- Seal Type shamir Initialized false Sealed true Total Shares 0 Threshold 0 Unseal Progress 0/0 Unseal Nonce n/a Version 1.8.3 Storage Type raft HA Enabled true`

However it's just looping and then the pods become good again and the UI remains accessible throughout the pods looping. What is causing the pods to loop through this message?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being an issue with my PVC.